# Prove existence of Jordan-Chevalley decomposition without using Jordan normal forms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

I was able to show that the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition of an $m \times m$ Jordan block $A$ is given by

$$A = \lambda \cdot Id_m + (A - \lambda \cdot Id_m)$$

Now I need to give a proof of the existence of the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition which does not use Jordan normal forms.

I am not even sure I understand the question. So am I just supposed to show that the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition exists for *any* matrix, not just Jordan blocks? Or am I supposed to prove the existence without using the concept of a "Jordan block" in my proof?

For context: this was a question on an exercise sheet provided by the university course I am taking.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give us some context for this question. Where did you come across it? Could you give us the **exact** wording of the question?

Comment: @BenGrossmann This was on an exercise sheet for Linear Algebra. The question was phrased almost exactly as I've written it  "give another proof of the existence of the Jordan–Chevalley decomposition which does not use Jordan normal forms."

Comment: The Wikipedia article does not use the full JCF Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Chevalley_decomposition

Comment: (ctd) only the existence of generalised eigenspaces which is trivial. Of course it depends on the field being perfect.